# Decrement date by day,hour,minute,second

Tags: oracle, datetime

I have the following code, which I use to create test data
that decrements in 5 minute intervals and is working fine.

```
Decrement 5 minutes 
SELECT  (DATE '2024-01-25' + 13/24) + (LEVEL-1) * (1/1440 * -5) dt  from dual  connect by level <= 10
```

Is there a syntax I can use to decrement by let's say (1 day 15 hours 14 minutes 13 seconds)  without converting to seconds or minutes?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks to all who answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [intervals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-B03DD036-66F8-4BD3-AF26-6D4433EBEC1C), either calculated via a function or as an [interval literal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-DC8D1DAD-7D04-45EA-9546-82810CD09A1B):

The equivalent for your 5-minute period would be:

```
DATE '2024-01-25' + INTERVAL '13' HOUR + ((LEVEL-1) * INTERVAL '5' MINUTE)
```

And for 1 day 15 hours 14 minutes 13 seconds you could use:

```
DATE '2024-01-25' + INTERVAL '13' HOUR + ((LEVEL-1) * INTERVAL '1 15:14:13' DAY TO SECOND)
```

So your code would then be:

```
SELECT DATE '2024-01-25' + INTERVAL '13' HOUR + ((LEVEL-1) * INTERVAL '1 15:14:13' DAY TO SECOND) dt
from dual
connect by level <= 10
```

| DT |
| --- |
| 2024-01-25 13:00:00 |
| 2024-01-27 04:14:13 |
| 2024-01-28 19:28:26 |
| 2024-01-30 10:42:39 |
| 2024-02-01 01:56:52 |
| 2024-02-02 17:11:05 |
| 2024-02-04 08:25:18 |
| 2024-02-05 23:39:31 |
| 2024-02-07 14:53:44 |
| 2024-02-09 06:07:57 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3HRmeNrQ)

You have to be a little careful as it's possible to try to generate an invalid date/time - e.g. by adding a year to a leap day (which errors because the following year won't be a leap year); or when working with timestamps with time zones, hitting a non-existent hour during a DST change. That shouldn't really be an issue here though.